# Ubuntu Android Studio Error running Emulator: Cannot decide host bitness. 32 bits assumed

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am reasonably sure I have a 64 bit Ubuntu box, and the first time I ran AndroidStudio the emulator ran just fine. The next time I ran it, the emulator refused to start up, saying:

> Cannot launch AVD in emulator. Output: WARNING: Cannot decide host
>   bitness because $SHELL is not properly defined; 32 bits assumed.
>   ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED, to use
>   them
>          you will have to do at least one of the following:
>          - Use the '-force-32bit' option when invoking 'emulator'.
>          - Set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to 'true' in your environment.
>          Either one will allow you to use the 32-bit binaries, but please be
>          aware that these will disappear in a future Android SDK release.
>          Consider moving to a 64-bit Linux system before that happens.

How do I properly define $SHELL such that it recognizes my 64 bit system?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my first run with Android-SDK instead of Android studio, I found the cause is that I'm using `zsh` as default shell.

Thus below commands work for me,

```
cd $ANDROID_SDK_HOME
SHELL=/bin/bash ./tools/android avd
```

Then I can start the emulator in AVD manager, if no `SHELL=/bin/bash` prepended, I had the same issue.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Under Docker image https://github.com/budtmo/docker-android, it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: same issue @david.perez, have you find the solution?

Comment: Any update for docker android?